# How to fill circle based on a value in CSS

Tags: html, css

```css
.circle
{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid;
  }
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  </div>
<div class="value">30</div>
```

If value is 30, I just want to fill the circle 30% with a color let it be red.
How do i do this using only css?

**EDIT** to answer @AMIT

```css
.fullCircle
{
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
  bordeR: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #f00;
  }
```

```html
<div class="fullCircle">
  </div>
```

It is 100% filled circle. So I hope you clear now what I mean by 30% filled circle.

If it is possible by CSS, it will be compatible. Why not?

**EDIT**

A google Image to answer `filled`
[link](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=partially+filled+circle&espv=2&biw=1440&bih=799&tbm=isch&imgil=w8gbqDKinF93nM%253A%253BO3RXx3jnK3Q-IM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.free-power-point-templates.com%25252Farticles%25252Fharvey-balls-in-powerpoint%25252F&source=iu&pf=m&fir=w8gbqDKinF93nM%253A%252CO3RXx3jnK3Q-IM%252C_&usg=__lkO5L1p3llO0-RG2J0ZGDn2yC4s%3D&ved=0CEEQyjdqFQoTCI2y4LbKm8gCFULipgodAV4NCQ&ei=AysKVs2kJsLEmwWBvLVI#imgrc=w8gbqDKinF93nM%3A&usg=__lkO5L1p3llO0-RG2J0ZGDn2yC4s%3D)

Comment: 1. what exactly do you mean "*fill the circle 30%*"? 2. what makes you think it's possible? (I'm not entirely certain it's not, but highly likely that it's not) 3. even if there was a way, it will certainly not be backward compatible with a substantial install base, is that any good at all?

Comment: I have closed the question as a dupe based on your update to the question.

Comment: No Problem harry, Let  me check whether It works for all cases. If not, I will edit the question

Comment: Actually your edit didn't answer my questions, but the linked answer did. In the future, try to describe exactly what you want, for example what does *filled* mean (Clockwise like the answer, middle -> out, circumference -> in, left -> right, transparent -> opaque or anything on your mind), 2nd, if you asked for a CSS solution only that reads the value from a text node on an unrelated element, how is the answer relevant?

Answer (score 10):

Use the `opacity`. It is a value between 0 (=transparent) and 1 (=opaque), so 30% is 0.3.

```css
.circle
{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  </div>
<div class="value">30</div>
```

**EDIT** based on your comment, you want 30% of the circle which is 360 degrees, so 360 x 30% = 108. To do so, use a `background-image`:

1. Draw a vertical red `linear-gradient`, meaning with -90 degree. This will fill half of the circle with red.
2. Draw a white `linear-gradient`with the degree -18 (=108-90). This will cover the part of the red half that exceeds 108 (30%).

```css
.circle
{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(18deg, white 50%, transparent 50%),
    linear-gradient(-90deg, red 50%, transparent 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="value">30</div>
```

Comment: No Racil. It would be better if you have two colors one tells completion part(30%) and another tell uncompleted(70%).

Comment: This is called **pie chart**. See my edit.

Comment: Yes, Thanks. I am trying to use calc in linear gradiant for calculations.